# Offer free places at events without generating £0 contributions

Tags: civievent

I'm using the 'regular fees' section of the Fees tab on the Events configuration screen to provide two options: one at £0 and one at £5.

When people sign up for the event at the free level, a £0 contribution is created.

I can see there's a certain stubborn logic here and that there may be situations where that's what's wanted, but is it possible to prevent the creation of these £0 contributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a price set instead where you just leave the checkbox for "required" unchecked when creating the price field. Then it outputs a "none" option automatically which doesn't create a contribution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try!